# JavaScript Math: How do I write this?

Tags: javascript

In Excel I have:

=(((SQRT(40))*($E$8/C16))^2)*1.1

Which is like:

(((SQRT(40)) * (7.695 / 0.200) ) ^2) *1.1;

I can't get it working in Javascript!

I have:

answer = (Math.exp(((Math.sqrt(40)) * (7.695 / 0.200))) *1.1);

I am getting something like: 5.265317066795887e+105

When I expect to get something like:  65168

Can anyone help see my error?

Comment: Does Excel really allow this as multiplication? (E1)1.1

Comment: @d03boy: I tried that in Excel 2007 and it says "Microsoft Office Excel found an error in the formula you entered. Do you want to accept the correction proposed below?" with the suggestion "=(E1)*1.1".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Math.exp(x)` is not x^2 but according to [the docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_exp.asp) e^x. You want to use `Math.pow(x,y)` ([doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp)) which means x^y instead. Use this expression:

```
answer = Math.pow(Math.sqrt(40) * (7.695 / 0.200), 2)*1.1;
```

Comment: The multiplication by `1.1` should be outside of `Math.pow`.

Comment: +1, although this might run faster? `answer = Math.sqrt(40) * 7.695 / 0.200; answer = 1.1 * answer * answer;`

Comment: I know old topic, but I accidentially got here, and realized that you were doing `sqrt(40) ^ 2`.. So a lot faster would be `answer = 44 * Math.pow( 7.695 / 0.200, 2 );`.